# html compiling in java

Tags: java, html

```
<html>
<style>
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Check</th><th>Actions</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>UI access</td><td>Login with supportAdmin user</td><td>OK</td><td>6332@devserver</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Server Status page</td><td>Windchill Directory Server available</td><td>OK</td><td>available</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>All 10 nodes up and running with sacch15711 as master</td><td>OK</td><td>All 1 are running with 6332@devserver as a master</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>All file servers available with status OK</td><td>OK</td><td>1 Available</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Check uptime of server matches the last restart</td><td>OK</td><td>03:50:47.935</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Queue Management</td><td>All Publisher queues are Enabled</td><td>OK</td><td>All Publisher Queues are enabled</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>All Publisher queues are Started</td><td>OK</td><td>All Publisher Queues are stated</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Publishing status</td><td>Check WVS Job Monitor for JobStatistics for job end date as each current day.Ensure good percentage of successful job is seen</td><td>OK</td><td>No job in WVS JOB Monitor for Today</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Vault Management</td><td>Master Vault is enabled</td><td>OK</td><td>All master vaults are enabled</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Master Vault Mount Status is Valid</td><td>OK</td><td>All Mounts are Valid</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Cache Vault is enabled</td><td>OK</td><td>all cache vaults are enabled</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Cache Vault Mount Status is Valid</td><td>OK</td><td>all Cache  Mounts  are Valid</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Current Activ Users</td><td>Active Users</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</html>
```

I am trying to build a html table in a java program and send it as a mail but the standalone html tends to be different after compiling in java
Below is the code.
"content" is of type StringBuffer

```
content.append("<!DOCTYPE html>"
                    + "<html>");
            content.append("<style>"
                    + "table.tableizer-table "
                    + "{font-size: 12px;border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} "
                    + ".tableizer-table td "
                    + "{padding: 4px;margin: 3px;border: 1px solid #CCC;}"
                    + ".tableizer-table th "
                    + "{background-color: #104E8B; color: #FFF;font-weight: bold;}"
                    + "</style>");
            content.append("<table class=\"tableizer-table\">"
                    + "<thead><tr class=\"tableizer-firstrow\">"
                    + "<th>Check</th>"
                    + "<th>Actions</th>"
                    + "<th>Status</th>"
                    + "<th>Comments</th></tr></thead>");
            content.append("<tbody><tr>"
                    + "<td>UI access</td>"
                    + "<td>Login with supportAdmin user</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>Server Status page</td>"
                    + "<td>Windchill Directory Server available</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td>All 10 nodes up and running with sacch15711 as master</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td>All file servers available with status OK</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td>Check uptime of server matches the last restart</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>Queue Management</td>"
                    + "<td>All Publisher queues are Enabled</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td>All Publisher queues are Started</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>Publishing status</td><td>Check WVS Job Monitor for JobStatistics for job end date as each current day.Ensure good percentage of successful job is seen</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>Vault Management</td>"
                    + "<td>Master Vault is enabled</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td>Master Vault Mount Status is Valid</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td>Cache Vault is enabled</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td>Cache Vault Mount Status is Valid</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>Current Active Users</td>"
                    + "<td>Active Users</td>"
                    + "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                    + "<td></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            content.append("</tbody>"
                    + "</table>"
                    + "</html>");
```

After Compiling my result looks like this in the browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZn1X.jpg)

The html table should ideally look like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaX59.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a couple of options here. I wouldn't recommend using StringBuilder, instead:

1. Use template engines like **Thymeleaf** or **Velocity** [example 1](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springmail) [example 2](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-compose-html-emails-in-java-with-spring-and-velocity/)
2. If you must build your HTML in Java consider **JSoup** - https://jsoup.org/